# Input File component error messages

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I'm facing a serious problem with ice:inputFile component.
When an error occurred while uploading process (like : invalid file name error, empty file name error, exceeding max size error), i use ice:message tag to show these error messages.
I use ice:panelPopup and display the ice:inputFile component inside it.
The problem is : when i toggle the uploading popup the error message still appears, i need any way to clear these messagses.

Please help me, any help is appreciated......................... :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, if I understood your question correctly, however I guess that the **immediate** keyword, applied on the action, which triggers the popup, will help you.

```
<ice:commandLink
   action="#{this.popup}"
   immediate="true">
      <h:outputText value="foo" />
</ice:commandLink>
```

In regular JSF Life Cycle, *action events* are normally fired after the Process Validations phase. Additionally, values will be updated from the UI to the model.

The **immediate** property, which is available to basically every JSF component which can cause any kind of event, bypasses validation and, depending on the event type, also the Model Update phase.

[alt text http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/3900/jsfimmediatecomponents.png](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/3900/jsfimmediatecomponents.png)
(Geary, Horstmann, 2008. Core JavaServer Faces - Second Edition. Prentice Hall)

You'll find more information on this topic in Suns JSF Tutorial: [The immediate Attribute](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSFPage5.html#wp128752)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things that have worked for me.

Bind your ice:inputFile component to a property on your backing bean and manually call the reset method on the property when you close the popup pane.

`<ice:inputFile binding="#{Bean.uploadedFile}"/>`

```
class BackingBean {
    private UICommand uploadedFile;

    public UICommand getUploadedFile() { return uploadedFile; }
    public void setUploadedFile(UICommand uploadedFile) { this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile; }

    public void onClose(ActionEvent event) {
        ((InputFile) uploadedFile).reset();
    }
}
```

-OR-

Add an actionListener to your ice:inputFile component. This will stop the inputFile component from adding its own validation errors to the context. You can implement whatever validation you need in the actionListener method and display the validation errors using an ice:messages tag. I've found that this works better than relying on inputFile's validation because it gives you complete control over the error message text/style and because the error messages clear automatically when the popup pane goes away.

`<ice:inputFile actionListener="#{Bean.onFileUpload}"/>`

```
public class BackingBean {
    public void onFileUpload(ActionEvent event) {
        FileInfo info = ((InputFile) event.getSource()).getFileInfo();
        switch (info.getStatus()) {
            case FileInfo.SAVED :
                // handle uploaded file
            case FileInfo.SIZE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED :
                // file too big error
            ...
        }   
    }
}
```